# How to select the time between NOW() and last row inserted?

Tags: mysql

What i basically need is a query that will allow me to display the time that has passed between last row inserted and the current time.

The specific table uses the *timestamp* field type.

I know that DATE_SUB must be used here, but i have no idea how to in this particular problem

Comment: You may want to subtract 2 datetime values: http://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/77102-elapsed-time-between-2-datetime-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select min(now() - timestamp) from table
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that table has a timestamp field which records the time-of-insertion for each record, then

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(now(), max(timestampfield))
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: Does not work, i get a mysql error that the query is invalid, starting from MAX, i thought maybe the interval keyword is missing, but i still get an error.